# Python Method Call

Tags: python, class, function, methods

```
class AlarmBox(Widget):


    hour = ["12","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
    tensMin = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    onesMin = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    day = ["AM", "PM"] 
    txt_inpt = ObjectProperty(None)


    def print1(self):
        self.txt_inpt.text("HI")

    XXXXXXX
```

How do I call print1 within the object?

I tried doing at XXXXXX

1. self.print1()
2. self.print1(self)
3. print1(self)
4. primt1()
5. c = AlarmBox()
6. c.print1()

in java you can do:

this.print1() or print1() !

Comment: did you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the outermost level (same indent level as `class AlarmBox`, you can declare code that is not part of that class:

```
c = AlarmBox()
c.print1()
```

The problem was that your code at `XXXXXX` was within the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in python as well, but you need to execute your code at some point:

```
class AlarmBox(Widget):


    hour = ["12","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
    tensMin = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    onesMin = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    day = ["AM", "PM"] 
    txt_inpt = ObjectProperty(None)


    def print1(self):
        self.txt_inpt.text("HI")

    # XXXXXXX

    def print1_caller(self):
        self.print1()
```

XXXXX is not a place to execute code, it's a place to define class members variables and methods.

Answer (score -1):

Use constructor

```
def __init__(self):
    self.print1()
```